# What options are there for taking timelapse photos with a Canon PowerShot SX520 HS?

Tags: canon, timelapse, remote

I have a Canon PowerShot SX520 HS. It does not have an inbuilt feature to take a picture after a specified interval, infinite number of times...

I went through this [post](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/80428/when-doing-a-manual-timelapse-is-it-better-to-leave-the-camera-on-or-turn-it-of), and I came across a something called a "remote trigger". Are there any time-lapse triggers compatible with my camera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not need any extra hardware. Check out [CHDK](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK) (Canon Hack Development Kit). It appears to provide the facilities that you are looking for, supports the SX520HS, and the developers claim that it does this without modifying a camera's firmware.

Comment: @deostroll Please report back to us (with your own answer) if you find CHDK useful. It will help other users who have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

CHDK might do the trick. [CHDK site](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK) among many other cool things, it includes an intervalometer. [LINK](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Take-Time-Lapse-Photos-CHDK/)

Comment: Great minds... (or nifty Googling)

Comment: Ha. I actually searched to see if Magic Lantern would work on that model and saw CHDK in the results. I tried it once a long time ago when I had a PowerShot but now I use a camera that uses ML.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Canon Powershot SX520 HS is a [*point-and-shoot* camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-and-shoot_camera) it is not compatible with remote controls.

Typically DSLR cameras have a [port on its' side](http://doc-diy.net/photo/eos_wired_remote/eos400d.jpg) to plug-in the remote control, which you could then set and lock the shutter open for as long as the remote is locked. Some higher-end DLSR's have this wireless instead.

You *could* use the built-in timer on your camera, though you would have to take many, many photos then composite them all into one photo in Photoshop... But that leads to its' own debate (composites vs one-picture exposed for several minutes/hours).

Comment: There are plenty of compact cameras that can use a remote control (either wired or wifi). But the SX520 can't. 
Also, not sure what a composite photo has to do with it. Are you confusing timelapse with long exposure?

Comment: Traditionally point-and-shoots don't have remote controls, I personally haven't seen any or used any in the couple decades shooting photography, but I'm not saying this is a definite either. 

I was offering a workaround for long exposures in case the poster wanted his camera to "bulb" a long exposure for star trails or something of that sort. Wouldn't recommend changing the camera's firmwire either.